# Comparison with using NoneType

Tags: python, python-2.7, logical-operators, nonetype

I tried some comparisons with `None`. Here are the tests -

```
1 > None
2 > None
0 > None
-100000 > None
```

All comparisons returned `True`. Why did this happen? Why did `NoneType` comparisons work with `intType`? Will the results be `True` in all cases?

Is it good coding practice to use `None` in comparisons?

---

**Note:** the comparisons only worked in **Python 2.x**. **Python 3.x** doesn't seem to support the comparisons (tested on *Python 2.7.6* and *Python 3.4.0*).

Comment: Hmm...what about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33049388)?

Comment: If you wanted to, you _could_ create a custom class that compares less than `None`. But generally, the only tests involving None should be identity tests, like `if a is None:`.